# How to modify XSD element from string to xml?

Tags: xml, xsd

I have the following part in my XSD:

```
 <xs:element name="Parameter">
   <xs:complexType mixed="true">
     <xs:attribute name="Name" use="required" type="xs:string"/>
   </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
```

which means that value for a Parameter can be any `string`. Can I somehow specify that value for Parameter can be  any valid `xml` like `<aaa></aaa>` ? Something like `type="xs:xml"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use

```
<xs:element name="Parameter" type="myType>
```

where

```
<complexType name="myType>
<choice>
<element "myXml" type="xml">
<element "myStr" type="xs:sting">
</choice>
</complexType>
```

and you will have to define xml like a pattern of xml you want to be your value.

Answer (score 2):

Use `<xs:any>` to allow any XML elements in your content model.

```
<xs:element name="Parameter">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

You can restrict elements allowed by `<xs:any>` to certain namespaces with `namespace` attribute and control their validation with `processContents` attribute. To allow any attribute, use `<xs:anyAttribute>`

More info in the XML Schema recommendation: [3.10.2 XML Representation of Wildcard Schema Components](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#declare-openness)

Comment: Parameter still can have value "dfdf" I want to have only valid xml for value

Comment: @Dominating With the code I had in my answer it cannot have text only content. Are you sure your code matches my example? Do you still have that `mixed="true" attribute in your `<complexType>` element? Because if you do have it, then also text only content is allowed.