# Way of skipping choice tags in xml validation

Tags: xml, xsd

I have the following XSD:

```
  <xs:element name="Parameter" type="complex">
  </xs:element>
  <xs:complexType name="complex">   
    <xs:choice>
      <xs:element name="MyData" type="myData"/>
      <xs:element name="String" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:choice>
    <xs:attribute name="Name" use="required" type="xs:string"/>   
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="myData">     
     <xs:attribute name="X" use="required" type="xs:integer"/> 
     <xs:attribute name="Y" use="required" type="xs:integer"/> 
  </xs:complexType>
```

when i validate this

```
<Parameter Name="P"><MyData X="1" Y="2"></MyData></Parameter>
```

everything is OK, but when i try to validate this:

```
        <Parameter Name="P">5r5r5r5r</Parameter>
```

it says **"The element 'Parameter' cannot contain text. List of possible elements expected: 'MyData, String'."**  Is there a way to skip putting `<Sring></String>` around "5r5r5r5r"?

Comment: why deleting whole question if you can just use edit?

Answer (score 0):

What do you really want?
If you want to write inside a Parameter tag you should define it like that:

```
<xs:element name="Parameter" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
```

Comment: Nope i want to put value but I want  when I dont put valid MyData value to take everything else for string... now it takes only <String>*</String>  for string and other for not valid...

Comment: Yup, that's how it goes. I don't think it could be element a complex and simple type at the same moment. I would define new element, maybe with a name "SimpleParameter" and make it type of xs:string.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that you want to have a `<Parameter>` element that can contain other elements or text. This can be achieved by allowing mixed content by setting attribute `mixed="true"` on `<xs:complexType>` or `<xs:complexContent>` element.

Sample code below.

```
<xs:element name="Parameter">
  <xs:complexType mixed="true">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="MyData" type="MyData"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="Name" use="required" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="Parameter">
```

**Note:** mixed type allows element to have **any** of these possible content choices

- only text
- only elements
- both text and elements so that text can appear

  - before the elements
  - after the elements
  - in between the elements
  - or any combination of the above-mentioned.

[You](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6136934/how-to-modify-xsd-element-from-string-to-xml) [have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6211951/problem-with-restriction-in-xsd) [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212878/way-of-skipping-choice-tags-in-xml-validation) questions that all revolve around the same subject. If these answers don't really address your problem then I'm asking you to specify what all requirements you actually want to fulfil.

- Is it allowed that element can contain both text and sub-elements at the same time?
- Does the text content need to be restricted to some format?
- Can the possible sub-elements be any elements or are they restricted to some known elements?
- Do you need to be able to validate the sub elements, if they can be any elements?